# How do I output two array lists side by side with different lengths

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I deleted my previous post.. Here is the info for my problem and how to reproduce the issue

> since the user inputted in the **right** amount of strings to
>   match originalR6 length
>             everything went dandy. BUT when say the user enters in less strings then originalR6, so now originalR6 is
>             bigger then userInputR6. When complied it returns **index out of range**
>             To see the issue in hand please comment out the nomad,maverick,lion in the userInput
>             method and uncomment the nomad,maverick

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestMain main = new TestMain();
    main.addAll();

    //user input
    main.userInput();
    main.printAll();
}

ArrayList<String> originalR6 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> userInputR6 = new ArrayList<String>();

public void addAll() {
    //Our set list of characters
    Collections.addAll(originalR6,"nomad", "maverick", "lion");
}

public void userInput() {
    userInputR6.add("nomad");
    userInputR6.add("maverick");
    userInputR6.add("lion");
    //--------------
   // userInputR6.add("lion");
   // userInputR6.add("lion");
}

public void printAll() {
    for (int i = 0; i <originalR6.size() ; i++) {
        System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + originalR6.get(i) + "\t" + (i+1) + ". " + userInputR6.get(i));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the required output if they are not same size ? Please show an example

Answer (score 1):

You should print until the smaller index, and then ^rint the bigger list of the 2, I used `printf` as it allows to get an alignement :

```
public void printAll() {
    int minSize = Math.min(originalR6.size(), userInputR6.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < minSize; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d. %-10s %d. %-10s%n", (i + 1), originalR6.get(i), (i + 1), userInputR6.get(i));
    }
    if (originalR6.size() < userInputR6.size()) {
        for (int i = minSize; i < userInputR6.size(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d. %-10s %d. %-10s%n", (i + 1), "/", (i + 1), userInputR6.get(i));
        }
    } else if (originalR6.size() > userInputR6.size()) {
        for (int i = minSize; i < originalR6.size(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d. %-10s %d. %-10s%n", (i + 1), originalR6.get(i), (i + 1), "/");
        }
    }
}
```

To get

- case `if`

  ```
  1. nomad      1. nomad     
  2. maverick   2. maverick  
  3. lion       3. /
  ```
- case  `else if`

  ```
  1. nomad      1. nomad     
  2. maverick   2. maverick  
  3. lion       3. lion      
  4. /          4. lion      
  5. /          5. lion
  ```

Answer (score 0):

When indexing two 'arrays' of data, if you try to index past the the last element in your array/list, you'll get `index out of range`, as there's only the abyss after the last element.

```
for (int i = 0; i <originalR6.size() && i <userInputR6.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + originalR6.get(i) + "\t" + (i+1) + ". " + userInputR6.get(i));
}
```

Adding in `i <userInputR6.size()` as an additional condition into your for loop condition will stop your `index out of range` error, the elements printed out will simply ignore the rest of the longer array/list.

Comment: @azro has a much more complete solution

Comment: You should add your propostion in your code, because now you just paste the OP's code

Comment: @DarceVader Sorta what I want but I need the rest of the originalR6 arrayList to print.. Thanks for the help though